# Multiple gems from same jRuby project

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am creating a jRuby gem at the moment and I may need to expose different commands (from the bin folder) to different type of users. Is that a good standard to create different gems for that, such as "_userX" or "_userY"? (And also the gem name may be different from the project name, which I know it's not a standard)

So I my need something like "mygem_for_admin_users" vs. "mygem_for_normal_users".

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? For example, are you saying you want a gem like mygem_freeware vs. mygem_paid, or more like mygem_for_admin_users vs. mygem_for_normal_users?

Comment: yeah more like mygem_for_admin_users vs. mygem_for_normal_users

Answer (score 1):

It definitely works, and there are definitely people doing it (example: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver).

This is obviously very subjective, but I personally feel that it's bad practice to have a gemspec that doesn't match the project name, or multiple gemspecs in a single project. Ultimately, if it's the cleanest solution to the problem, it's the cleanest solution, and you should go for it, but first consider other ways of going about it:

- You could have one base gem and 2+ interface gems that expose different sets of commands from the base gem.
- You could somehow identify the different classes of users from the library itself, making all the commands available, but some of them restricted unless the right user type is set
- You could build everything into one command with many subcommands (like bundle or git) that does the same reasoning about user types

There may be more options.

TL;DR: It's not great practice, but people do it and nothing will catch on fire. Just make sure that there isn't an easy way to avoid it first.